# how to subtract time-series from gridded time-series

Tags: python-xarray

I have a dataset with time-series in 44 locations.

It has the following dimensions: time: 9784, latitude:44, longitude:44.
I need to subtract an array of (9784,) shape from each time-step at each location.
Simple

```
ds1 = data_locations.values- average
```

returns an error:

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9784,44,44)
> (9784,)

So I figured I need to use lambda

```
ds_new = xr.apply_ufunc((lambda x: x - average, axis=0),data_locations)
```

But it returns an error as well by saying the syntax is invalid.
It should be simple but I cannot see how to make sure an operation is applied to time dimension.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize `xarray`'s broadcasting using the named dimensions here. Xarray will automatically subtract arrays/datasets as long as their dimensions and coordinates match.

#### Example

Create synthetic data

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data_locations = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature').load()
data_locations
```

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 25, time: 2920, lon: 53)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 75.0 72.5 70.0 67.5 65.0 ... 25.0 22.5 20.0 17.5 15.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 200.0 202.5 205.0 207.5 ... 322.5 325.0 327.5 330.0
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2013-01-01 ... 2014-12-31T18:00:00
Data variables:
    air      (time, lat, lon) float32 241.2 242.5 243.5 ... 296.5 296.2 295.7
```

Create averages

```py
average = xr.DataArray(np.arange(ds['time'].size), 
                       dims=("time"), 
                       coords={"time": ds['time']})
```

Subtract the two

```py
result = data_locations - average
```

The result is as desired, which you can check e.g. by looking at the differences for each time coordinate

```py
# Differences are all 10 here
data_locations.isel(time=10) - result.isel(time=10)
```

Comment: It actually did not work. What was returned is an xarray dataarray with dimensions
time:0, latitude: 44, longitude: 44.

Comment: Does my synthetic example work for you? If so, then could you please provide a reproducible example, or at least your code in the question?